How to add manual approval between terraform plan and apply stage running in the github actions job?
I'm trying to create github actions workflows to deploy our infrastructure. I have suggested the way of createing a new branch and pushing updated code to it and when you want to plan you need to create a pr and if you want to apply you need to approve the pr. But my team wants me to use workflow dispatch to manually to the plan and manually approve the apply.
please suggest what can be done so that when triggered the workflow manually, it should run the terraform plan and wait for approval to run the apply. I'm ok if can be done in same job or different jobs.
Currently I have created 2 jobs but once the plan job is done it automtically triggers the second job. Want to add a manual approval before the job moves into the second job. also facing issue with


Is this what you need? https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/reviewing-deployments

did you get the solution?
